# How do I blit-animate new artists with matplotlib's FuncAnimation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I'm trying to create an animated figure for showing multiple tens of thousands of data points, appearing over time, in a single figure. Using `blit=True` to avoid redrawing everything every frame doesn't work without telling it to redraw everything every frame - I want to just draw the new data points.

Neither [python matplotlib update scatter plot from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722691/python-matplotlib-update-scatter-plot-from-a-function) or [How to animate a scatter plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401658/how-to-animate-a-scatter-plot) answer the question because I want to add new artists, not just update existing ones with `set_offsets`, which forces every point to be redrawn. The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib-animation-funcanimation) says that it does support new artists:

> *func* must return an iterable of all artists that were modified or created

I'm running matplotlib 3.1.1 on macOS 10.13 *and* RHEL7 - the MacOSX backend doesn't work *at all* for me with blitting, so manually selecting TkAgg on that system:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg") # On macOS

import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def animate(n):
    scatter = ax1.scatter([n], [n])
    return [scatter]


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_xlim(0, 20)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 20)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

But when running this, only the last plotted data point remains on the figure:
[image: Animation only showing single artist]

How can I use blitting to write new data points **without** drawing everything every frame?

Comment: Have a look here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42738014/10640534) and here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43680172/10640534).

Comment: Yes, I viewed both of those, and both are answering different questions. Neither of them handle a) blitting or b) adding new artists. If I update an existing artist, all X0,000 points are redrawn every frame, which quickly becomes very slow.

Comment: I've updated the question to hopefully make it clearer that neither of those questions actually answer it, just answer a different question about the same topic

Comment: Would the following work for you then? `import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def animate(n):
    scatter = ax.scatter(n, n)
    if n == 0:
        return ax.get_children()[0],
    else:
        return ax.get_children()[:n]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 20)
ax.set_ylim(0, 20)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100, blit=True)
plt.show()`

Comment: After further research, I think this isn't actually possible like I want - I dove into the animation code and it deliberately clears the axis back to the original every frame. Looks like the standard animation classes are just for drawing on top of a complicated base. I have an example of it working which is why I thought it was possible, but I think that is accidentally causing a refresh anyway. I'll self-answer when I'm a bit more certain.

Comment: What about the piece of code here (https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#funcanimation), the one that plots a sine function? Does not it do what you want?